# Laravel mimes validation rule not working for Microsoft Word Documents

Tags: php, laravel, validation, mime-types, laravel-validation

I'm trying to upload .docx file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTECM.png)

My validation rules:

```
     return [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'latin_nameable', 'min:2', 'max:20'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'latin_nameable', 'min:2', 'max:20'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'location' => ['required', Rule::exists('city', 'city_id')->where(static function 
           (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('vacancy', 1);
          })],
        'skype' => ['required_without_all:phone', 'min:2', 'regex:/^[0-9A-Za-z.-_:]+$/'],
        'phone' => ['required_without_all:skype', 'phone:AUTO'],

        'cv' => 'mimes:docx,doc',
        'linkedin' => ['nullable', 'required_without_all:cv', 'url', 
                 'regex:/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?([\w]+\.)?linkedin\.com\/(pub|in|profile)/'],
        'accept' => ['accepted'],
        'is_policy_read' => ['accepted'],
        'is_referrer_informed' => ['accepted'],
    ];
```

My Controller:

```
public function store(StoreReferralRequest $request): JsonResponse
{
    $referral = $this->referralRepo->createNewReferral($request, 
    $this->referralCvRepo, $this->user->id, $this->vacancyRepo);
    $referral->consent()->create([self::IS_POLICY_READ => (int)$request->get(self::IS_POLICY_READ),
        self::IS_REFERER_INFORMED => (int) $request->get(self::IS_REFERER_INFORMED),
    ]);

    #generate request data
    $requestData = $this->referralRepo->generateStoreRequestData($referral);
    #dispatch Create referral job
    $this->dispatch(new ReferralCreateJob($referral->id, $requestData, self::API_CREATE_URL));
    $this->referralRepo->sendReferralEmployerEmail($this->emailService, $referral);

    return response()->json(['updateUrl' => route('my::referral.update', [$referral->id])], Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

I got 422 response with message: cv: ["The CV must be a file of type: docx, doc."].

Can someone help?

Comment: Please post your controller also.